# visual studio package manager entity framework core version and .net framework error

Tags: visual-studio-code, package

I am getting .net framework v4.7.2 framework compatibility error while installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkcore 6.0.21 version in the entity section of my visual studio layered architecture project.

I got the same error when I tried to install Microsoft Entity framework core version 7.0.11

Comment: When installing Microsoft entity frameworkcore version 6.0.21, I get .net version 4.7.2 framework compatibility error.
I'm trying to do a layered architecture project, I would be glad if you could help me.